# (Angular) ngx-translate Feature Module not extending Parent Module’s translations

Tags: angular, parent, ngx-translate

I am lazy loading feature module. And making it import TranslateModule.forChild() with extend true.(loading feature specific translations)

In app.module i am importing TranslateModule.forRoot. (Loading common translations)

Now i can access only feature module’s translation only from feature component. I can see in network the parent’s translation is getting loaded but could not access it.

Anyone knows the solution for this. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using multihttploader npm package. Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 0):

I have used as below the translation module.

**In app.module.ts:**

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
     useClass: CustomTranslateLoader
  }
 })
```

**In shared.module.ts:**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TranslateModule
  ],
  exports: [
     TranslateModule
  ],

})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But you overlooked the question..

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps of this links-

```
https://www.techiediaries.com/angular/angular-9-internationalization-ngx-translate-tutorial-example/

https://www.positronx.io/angular-internationalization-i18n-with-ngx-translate-tutorial/
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the docs are for beginners.